# Magento StackExchange CSS Issue

Tags: bug

When I tried to flag a comment today. I found when I select an option of something else a text area displays which slides down the submit button due to which we cannot submit the form.

Please refer the screen shot

[image]

Comment: I think now its working fine

Comment: Have the same issue in Firefox. Tried in private window.

Comment: For me its showing correctly can you please mention your firefox version and device resolution for more